# ImagePicker never returning value flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to prompt users of my app to upload photos. However, I'm have an issue. The function where I try to get the gallery image always returns null / never completes.

This i my code:

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                final image =
                    await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

                if (image != null) {
                  print(image.path);
                  print('exists');
                }
              },
```

It never prints 'exists' or image.path, I don't know whats wrong.

I have added this to info.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>For image upload and verification</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>For image upload and ID verification</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app uses the microphone for videos</string>
```

Package version: ^0.8.4

Would be really thankful for some input!

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator?

Comment: Correct @WillHlas

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known issue for IOS 14+ on the simulator. Hopefully this will be fixed soon but I haven't found a solution yet!

Comment: Like Will said, known issue. If you use a physical device you should be fine.